# is it meaning full to use child process and clustering at same time in node.js

Tags: node.js

Is it  meaningful to  use child process and clustering at same time ? for example enable clustering for whole app and  use child process for some block event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have concern with application load balancer you either used Nginx or Apache for this and try to make hybird application for calculation process